# dpkg-buildpackage error when trying to run bitbake on argh

Tags: raspberry-pi, yocto, bitbake

I get the following issue:

```
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
| NOTE: make -j 4
| dpkg-buildpackage -A -uc -us
| make: dpkg-buildpackage: No such file or directory
| make: *** [Makefile:2: deb] Error 127
| ERROR: oe_runmake failed
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Execution of '/home/adrian/yocto/rpi-build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/python3-argh/0.28.1-r0/temp/run.do_compile.3091522' failed with exit code 1
```

after running bitbake argh. This is after adding it in using devtool add and devtool finish.

Here is my local.conf and my bblayers.conf:

```
#
# This file is your local configuration file and is where all local user settings
# are placed. The comments in this file give some guide to the options a new user
# to the system might want to change but pretty much any configuration option can
# be set in this file. More adventurous users can look at local.conf.extended
# which contains other examples of configuration which can be placed in this file
# but new users likely won't need any of them initially.
#
# Lines starting with the '#' character are commented out and in some cases the
# default values are provided as comments to show people example syntax. Enabling
# the option is a question of removing the # character and making any change to the
# variable as required.

#
# Machine Selection
#
# You need to select a specific machine to target the build with. There are a selection
# of emulated machines available which can boot and run in the QEMU emulator:
#
#MACHINE ?= "qemuarm"
#MACHINE ?= "qemuarm64"
#MACHINE ?= "qemumips"
#MACHINE ?= "qemumips64"
#MACHINE ?= "qemuppc"
#MACHINE ?= "qemux86"
#MACHINE ?= "qemux86-64"
#
# There are also the following hardware board target machines included for 
# demonstration purposes:
#
#MACHINE ?= "beaglebone-yocto"
#MACHINE ?= "genericx86"
#MACHINE ?= "genericx86-64"
#MACHINE ?= "edgerouter"
#
MACHINE ?= "raspberrypi-cm3"
# This sets the default machine to be qemux86-64 if no other machine is selected:
#MACHINE ??= "qemux86-64"

IMAGE_FSTYPES =" rpi-sdimg"
#
# Where to place downloads
#
# During a first build the system will download many different source code tarballs
# from various upstream projects. This can take a while, particularly if your network
# connection is slow. These are all stored in DL_DIR. When wiping and rebuilding you
# can preserve this directory to speed up this part of subsequent builds. This directory
# is safe to share between multiple builds on the same machine too.
#
# The default is a downloads directory under TOPDIR which is the build directory.
#
#DL_DIR ?= "${TOPDIR}/downloads"

#
# Where to place shared-state files
#
# BitBake has the capability to accelerate builds based on previously built output.
# This is done using "shared state" files which can be thought of as cache objects
# and this option determines where those files are placed.
#
# You can wipe out TMPDIR leaving this directory intact and the build would regenerate
# from these files if no changes were made to the configuration. If changes were made
# to the configuration, only shared state files where the state was still valid would
# be used (done using checksums).
#
# The default is a sstate-cache directory under TOPDIR.
#
#SSTATE_DIR ?= "${TOPDIR}/sstate-cache"

#
# Where to place the build output
#
# This option specifies where the bulk of the building work should be done and
# where BitBake should place its temporary files and output. Keep in mind that
# this includes the extraction and compilation of many applications and the toolchain
# which can use Gigabytes of hard disk space.
#
# The default is a tmp directory under TOPDIR.
#
#TMPDIR = "${TOPDIR}/tmp"

#
# Default policy config
#
# The distribution setting controls which policy settings are used as defaults.
# The default value is fine for general Yocto project use, at least initially.
# Ultimately when creating custom policy, people will likely end up subclassing 
# these defaults.
#
DISTRO ?= "poky"
# As an example of a subclass there is a "bleeding" edge policy configuration
# where many versions are set to the absolute latest code from the upstream 
# source control systems. This is just mentioned here as an example, its not
# useful to most new users.
# DISTRO ?= "poky-bleeding"

#
# Package Management configuration
#
# This variable lists which packaging formats to enable. Multiple package backends
# can be enabled at once and the first item listed in the variable will be used
# to generate the root filesystems.
# Options are:
#  - 'package_deb' for debian style deb files
#  - 'package_ipk' for ipk files are used by opkg (a debian style embedded package manager)
#  - 'package_rpm' for rpm style packages
# E.g.: PACKAGE_CLASSES ?= "package_rpm package_deb package_ipk"
# We default to rpm:
PACKAGE_CLASSES ?= "package_rpm package_deb package_ipk"

#
# SDK target architecture
#
# This variable specifies the architecture to build SDK items for and means
# you can build the SDK packages for architectures other than the machine you are
# running the build on (i.e. building i686 packages on an x86_64 host).
# Supported values are i686 and x86_64
#SDKMACHINE ?= "i686"

#
# Extra image configuration defaults
#
# The EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES variable allows extra packages to be added to the generated
# images. Some of these options are added to certain image types automatically. The
# variable can contain the following options:
#  "dbg-pkgs"       - add -dbg packages for all installed packages
#                     (adds symbol information for debugging/profiling)
#  "src-pkgs"       - add -src packages for all installed packages
#                     (adds source code for debugging)
#  "dev-pkgs"       - add -dev packages for all installed packages
#                     (useful if you want to develop against libs in the image)
#  "ptest-pkgs"     - add -ptest packages for all ptest-enabled packages
#                     (useful if you want to run the package test suites)
#  "tools-sdk"      - add development tools (gcc, make, pkgconfig etc.)
#  "tools-debug"    - add debugging tools (gdb, strace)
#  "eclipse-debug"  - add Eclipse remote debugging support
#  "tools-profile"  - add profiling tools (oprofile, lttng, valgrind)
#  "tools-testapps" - add useful testing tools (ts_print, aplay, arecord etc.)
#  "debug-tweaks"   - make an image suitable for development
#                     e.g. ssh root access has a blank password
# There are other application targets that can be used here too, see
# meta/classes/image.bbclass and meta/classes/core-image.bbclass for more details.
# We default to enabling the debugging tweaks.
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES ?= "debug-tweaks dev-pkgs ssh-server-openssh" 
IMAGE_FEATURES_append = " package-management"
#
# Additional image features
#
# The following is a list of additional classes to use when building images which
# enable extra features. Some available options which can be included in this variable
# are:
#   - 'buildstats' collect build statistics
#   - 'image-mklibs' to reduce shared library files size for an image
#   - 'image-prelink' in order to prelink the filesystem image
# NOTE: if listing mklibs & prelink both, then make sure mklibs is before prelink
# NOTE: mklibs also needs to be explicitly enabled for a given image, see local.conf.extended
USER_CLASSES ?= "buildstats image-mklibs image-prelink"

#
# Runtime testing of images
#
# The build system can test booting virtual machine images under qemu (an emulator)
# after any root filesystems are created and run tests against those images. It can also
# run tests against any SDK that are built. To enable this uncomment these lines.
# See classes/test{image,sdk}.bbclass for further details.
#IMAGE_CLASSES += "testimage testsdk"
#TESTIMAGE_AUTO_qemuall = "1"

IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " \
    nodejs \
    nodejs-npm \
    nodejs-systemtap \
    rng-tools \
    argh \
    python3-core \
    python3-setuptools \
    python3-pip \
    python3-dev \
    python3-lxml \
    python3-six \
    python3-spidev \
    curl \
    sudo \
    netcat \
    bash \
    tar \
    sed \
    openssl \
    openssl-bin \
    lighttpd \
    iproute2 \
    watchdog \
    dhcp-client \
    avahi-daemon \
    avahi-utils \
    avahi-autoipd \ 
    connman \
    connman-client \
    busybox \
    resolvconf \
    pkgconfig \
    opkg \
    python3-spidev \
    python3-twisted \
    ntp \   
    tzdata \
    raspi-gpio \
    rpi-gpio \
    rpio \
    "

#
# Interactive shell configuration
#
# Under certain circumstances the system may need input from you and to do this it
# can launch an interactive shell. It needs to do this since the build is
# multithreaded and needs to be able to handle the case where more than one parallel
# process may require the user's attention. The default is iterate over the available
# terminal types to find one that works.
#
# Examples of the occasions this may happen are when resolving patches which cannot
# be applied, to use the devshell or the kernel menuconfig
#
# Supported values are auto, gnome, xfce, rxvt, screen, konsole (KDE 3.x only), none
# Note: currently, Konsole support only works for KDE 3.x due to the way
# newer Konsole versions behave
#OE_TERMINAL = "auto"
# By default disable interactive patch resolution (tasks will just fail instead):
PATCHRESOLVE = "noop"

#
# Disk Space Monitoring during the build
#
# Monitor the disk space during the build. If there is less that 1GB of space or less
# than 100K inodes in any key build location (TMPDIR, DL_DIR, SSTATE_DIR), gracefully
# shutdown the build. If there is less that 100MB or 1K inodes, perform a hard abort
# of the build. The reason for this is that running completely out of space can corrupt
# files and damages the build in ways which may not be easily recoverable.
# It's necesary to monitor /tmp, if there is no space left the build will fail
# with very exotic errors.
BB_DISKMON_DIRS ??= "\
    STOPTASKS,${TMPDIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,${DL_DIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,${SSTATE_DIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,/tmp,100M,100K \
    ABORT,${TMPDIR},100M,1K \
    ABORT,${DL_DIR},100M,1K \
    ABORT,${SSTATE_DIR},100M,1K \
    ABORT,/tmp,10M,1K"


#
# Shared-state files from other locations
#
# As mentioned above, shared state files are prebuilt cache data objects which can
# used to accelerate build time. This variable can be used to configure the system
# to search other mirror locations for these objects before it builds the data itself.
#
# This can be a filesystem directory, or a remote url such as http or ftp. These
# would contain the sstate-cache results from previous builds (possibly from other
# machines). This variable works like fetcher MIRRORS/PREMIRRORS and points to the
# cache locations to check for the shared objects.
# NOTE: if the mirror uses the same structure as SSTATE_DIR, you need to add PATH
# at the end as shown in the examples below. This will be substituted with the
# correct path within the directory structure.
#SSTATE_MIRRORS ?= "\
#file://.* http://someserver.tld/share/sstate/PATH;downloadfilename=PATH \n \
#file://.* file:///some/local/dir/sstate/PATH"

#
# Yocto Project SState Mirror
#
# The Yocto Project has prebuilt artefacts available for its releases, you can enable
# use of these by uncommenting the following line. This will mean the build uses
# the network to check for artefacts at the start of builds, which does slow it down
# equally, it will also speed up the builds by not having to build things if they are
# present in the cache. It assumes you can download something faster than you can build it
# which will depend on your network.
#
#SSTATE_MIRRORS ?= "file://.* http://sstate.yoctoproject.org/all/PATH;downloadfilename=PATH"

#
# Qemu configuration
#
# By default native qemu will build with a builtin VNC server where graphical output can be
# seen. The line below enables the SDL UI frontend too.
PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-qemu-system-native = " sdl"
# By default libsdl2-native will be built, if you want to use your host's libSDL instead of 
# the minimal libsdl built by libsdl2-native then uncomment the ASSUME_PROVIDED line below.
#ASSUME_PROVIDED += "libsdl2-native"

# You can also enable the Gtk UI frontend, which takes somewhat longer to build, but adds
# a handy set of menus for controlling the emulator.
#PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-qemu-system-native = " gtk+"

#
# Hash Equivalence
#
# Enable support for automatically running a local hash equivalence server and
# instruct bitbake to use a hash equivalence aware signature generator. Hash
# equivalence improves reuse of sstate by detecting when a given sstate
# artifact can be reused as equivalent, even if the current task hash doesn't
# match the one that generated the artifact.
#
# A shared hash equivalent server can be set with "<HOSTNAME>:<PORT>" format
#
#BB_HASHSERVE = "auto"
#BB_SIGNATURE_HANDLER = "OEEquivHash"
ENABLE_SPI_BUS = "1"
# CONF_VERSION is increased each time build/conf/ changes incompatibly and is used to
# track the version of this file when it was generated. This can safely be ignored if
# this doesn't mean anything to you.
CONF_VERSION = "1"
```

```
# POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION is increased each time build/conf/bblayers.conf
# changes incompatibly
POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION = "2"

BBPATH = "${TOPDIR}"
BBFILES ?= ""

BBLAYERS ?= " \
  ${TOPDIR}/../sources/poky/meta \
  ${TOPDIR}/../sources/poky/meta-poky \
  ${TOPDIR}/../sources/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
  ${TOPDIR}/../sources/meta-raspberrypi \
  ${TOPDIR}/../sources/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
  ${TOPDIR}/../sources/meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia \
  ${TOPDIR}/../sources/meta-openembedded/meta-networking \
  ${TOPDIR}/../sources/meta-openembedded/meta-python \
  "
```

And I got argh from here: https://pypi.org/project/argh/

Tried reinstalling make, tried a lot of other fixes for dpkg-buildpackage but none of them have worked

EDIT:
I think the issue has been resolved, I think I wasn't using devtool add and devtool finish to import the package from pypi